# Fuzzy logic simulation software

Tags: 16.04, software-recommendation, octave

I am trying to find the best fuzzy logic simulator for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. In Windows, I have fuzzy logic working in MATLAB, but in Ubuntu, Octave doesn't seem to compile fuzzy logic code.

Is there something I have to install to run fuzzy logic code in Octave? Also, what alternatives are there to Octave on Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested it, but it seems that [FuzzyLite Libraries for Fuzzy Logic Control](https://www.fuzzylite.com/) is great.
It may be installed from official repository with `sudo apt-get install fuzzylite`.

Octave is good alternative to MATLAB. 
You can install Octave from repository with
`sudo apt-get install octave liboctave-dev`
and then install [fuzzy-logic-toolkit](https://octave.sourceforge.io/fuzzy-logic-toolkit/index.html) in it with
`pkg install -forge fuzzy-logic-toolkit -verbose`.

Also do not forget [Scilab](http://scilab.org). You can install it with `sudo apt-get install scilab`.
Then install Scilab Fuzzy Logic Toolbox (sciFLT) from [GitHub](https://github.com/holgern/sciflt).